# On the nil but not nilpotent ideal counterexample.

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, nilpotence

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214594/an-ideal-which-is-nil-but-not-nilpotent) post, there is a counterexample where a nil ideal (ie every element is nilpotent) is *not* nilpotent.

More precisely, let's consider the polynomial ring 
$$R:=\Bbb C[X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots]/\langle X_1^2,X_2^3,X_3^4,\dots\rangle,$$
and set $I:=\langle X_1^2,X_2^3,X_3^4,\dots\rangle$.
Then we can consider the ideal 
$$\tilde I:=\langle X_1+I,X_2+I,X_3+I,\dots\rangle \trianglelefteq R.$$
But I can not see why this is a nil ideal. Normally, we should take an arbitrary element $\bar x$ of $\tilde I$ and show that there exists an $m\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $\bar x^m=0_R=I$.

Could you please help?

*Thanks.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your definition of a *nil ideal* is that every element is nilpotent.

It is an easy exercise that the sum of two nilpotent elements is still nilpotent.

Solution:

> suppose $x^m = y^n = 0$, then $(x + y)^{m + n - 1} = 0$ by binomial expansion.

Using induction, one can deduce that any finite sum of nilpotent elements is nilpotent.

Equally clear is that any multiple of a nilpotent element is also nilpotent.

Therefore, any ideal generated by (possibly infinitely many) nilpotent elements is nilpotent, because every element in the ideal is a finite sum of multiples of the generators.

This in particular applies to your $\tilde I$, which is generated by images of the $X_i$'s.

---

It seems that your definition of a *nilpotent ideal* is that there is an $n$ such that $I^n = 0$.

Then it's clear that $\tilde I$ is not nilpotent, since for every $n$, the ideal $\tilde I^n$ contains the image of $X_n^n$, which is nonzero in $R$.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. Could you please elaborate also why this is not nilpotent?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: You mean that for any positive integer $n$, it is $I\neq X_n^n+I \in \tilde I^n$. Right?

Comment: I mean for any $n$, the $n$-th power $\tilde I^n$ contains a nonzero element (namely the image of $X_n^n$), hence is nonzero.

Comment: The image of $X_n^n$ you mean the element $X_n^n+I\in \tilde I$?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is meant.

Comment: Thank you very much for all.